# javax.microedition.pki Certificate Failed Verification

Tags: java-me, httpconnection, midp-2.0

I'm trying to read in a JSON reply from the Google Sheets API in a Java ME MIDP application. I've tried the following with other addresses and it receives their content fine but the actual API I want to use is Sheets and it always returns an "Certificate Failed Verification" exception.

```
HttpConnection c = null;
InputStream is = null;
StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();
try
    {

     c = (HttpsConnection)Connector.open(urlstring);
     c.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
     c.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
     c.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Profile/MIDP-2.1 Configuration/CLDC-1.1");

     is = c.openInputStream();

     int len = (int)c.getLength();
     int ch;

     while ( (ch = is.read() ) != -1)
         {
         str.append((char)ch);
         }


    }

catch( Exception e ){ alert( ""+e ); }

return str.toString();
```

Connector.open() implicitly returns a HttpsConnection if the URL starts with Https so it should still work.

An example of a HTTPS request

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1
```

Which won't work but the above also allows for HTTP connections

```
http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1
```

Which will work.

Google Sheets however requires HTTPS and thus is not obtainable via the above code. How can I make a GET request over HTTPS to the sheets API? Thank you.

Comment: In the Sun Java Wireless Toolkit for CLDC you can set permissions MIDlet permissions. I've set the permission for javax.microedition.io.Connector.https but it still doesn't return any response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've gathered it seems that when connecting over HTTPS the phone uses an older version of SSL or TLS which has since been deprecated causing some API's to not respond.

I found that if you make an API request over HTTPs with the Opera Mini web browser it works. Giving you the desired response but on closer inspection it seems Opera gets the response for you and gives it back via a different URL. In attempt to furnish these older devices that cannot use a newer version of SSL/TLS to make the secure connection themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when implementing an online highscore system for one of our games. It would fetch highscores fine on some phones but didn't work on other phones. The explanation:
Some phones have their own built-in "MIME-type checker". When you call `(HttpConnection)Connector.open(urlstring)` the phone expects a `text/html` response. When it instead gets a `application/json` (or other) response, the phone gives its own "Not found" error.
Not sure if your problem is related, but worth a try? See if you can add a mime-type "application/json" in the request header of the `HttpConnection`.

Comment: That's got it to generate an exception. `javax.microedition.pki certificate failed verification` I've had a look online for this but can't find out much about it. It's a sony ericsson phone. I can't browse https with the default browser due to `Communication failure. Secure connection failed` but I can using the java app Opera Mini which I installed. I'll try look at the .java files in Opera and see how it deals with https

Comment: Actually it seems I can visit some sites over HTTPS with the default browser. Asks me if I want to continue. But only with some.

Comment: Could be confirming the suspicion. What Sony Ericsson model is it? Most Sony Ericsson models shouldn't give you any trouble, but there were a few models they didn't make themselves, like F305, which could act like this if visiting a website that returns content of a different mime-type.
Try adding mime-type `application/json; charset=UTF-8` in your request header.

Comment: I've updated the post with the new code but it still throws the cert failed verification exception. It's a W995. Was your jar signed with a certificate?

Comment: No I didn't sign my jar. It's not necessary. All it does is to skip the popup message. If you insist on signing your jar, remember you need to get a certificate from a trusted provider, like e.g. Thawte (which is expensive). Creating your own won't work.

Comment: I've decompiled the class files of the Opera Mini java app which works with https but it doesn't seem to do anything different? What else could I try?

Comment: Where did you get your certificate from?

Comment: It's not signed. I thought that might have been why Opera worked over HTTPs but it's jar isn't signed either.

Comment: That does indeed sound weird. Have you tried testing it on another phone?

Comment: I've tried it with other phones but same problem. Is there sort of man-in-the-middle website I could use that would get my HTTPS request but give it to me via a HTTP link? Kind of like a url shortener but doesn't redirect you. Can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: I think HTTPS certificates are stored on the phone. You even have options to add your own. Maybe Google requires that you add a certain certificate when using Sheets?